# How to convert C# razor code into vb.net Razor Code Block

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

I need help converting this c# razor code into VB.NET razor code.

```
 PageData["Colors"] = new[]{"LightCyan", "Gainsboro","Chocolate"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
PageData("Colors") = { "LightCyan", "Gainsboro", "Chocolate" }
```

Comment: Wow thanks. What the purpose of the "new []" in C#? How come in vb i there's no new?

Comment: It's collection initializer. You can read more about it for [`C#`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) and [`VB.NET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx). That's the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Darin Dimitrov.